# Awk with combination of cut and if

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk, cut

I have a file `test.txt` that contains :

```
1    1:?    1:0    0.762
2    1:?    2:1    0.754
3    1:?    2:1    0.848
4    1:?    1:0    1
5    1:?    2:1    0.851
```

In the third column, I try to retrieve the number after : and according to its value, I have to apply a different calculation on the last column. If it is a 0 then I have to return the value in column 4 by subtracting 1. And if it is a 1, then I have to return the value of the column 4.

I can retrieve the number after the : with the following command:

```
awk '{print $3}' test.txt | cut -d: -f 2
```

But I don't know how to continue. How can I do that?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: A column containing -0.238 for the 1st line, 0.754 for the second...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'split($3,a,":"){print a[2]?$4:$4-1}' file
```

or if you still want other field

```
awk 'split($3,a,":"){$4=a[2]?$4:$4-1}1' file
```

or even

```
awk 'split($3,a,":")&&!a[2]{$4--}1' file
```

ANOTHER

Only $4

```
awk '{$0=$4-($3~/:0$/)}1' file
```

Line

```
awk '{$4-=($3~/:0$/)}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with:

```
awk '$3 ~ /:0$/{print $4-1;next}{print $4}' test.txt
-0.238
0.754
0.848
0
0.851
```

If the 3rd column ends with `:0` (`$3 ~ /:0$/`) then print the 4th column minus 1; else print the 4th column.

Comment: Could also do `awk '{print $3~/:0$/?--$4:$4}'`

Comment: @Jidder `awk '{$0=$3~/:0$/?--$4:$4}1'`

Comment: @jotne yeah i though of that but it only saved 2 characters and people seem to hate it compared to print.

Comment: @Jidder hmm yes, it seem to be hard for many to understand the `1` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{split($3,a,":"); if(!a[2]){$4=$4-1}}1' OFS="    " file (with split)
```

Example:

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ cat file
1    1:?    1:0    0.762
2    1:?    2:1    0.754
3    1:?    2:1    0.848
4    1:?    1:0    1
5    1:?    2:1    0.851
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ awk '{split($3,a,":"); if(!a[2]){$4=$4-1}}1' OFS="    " file
1    1:?    1:0    -0.238
2    1:?    2:1    0.754
3    1:?    2:1    0.848
4    1:?    1:0    0
5    1:?    2:1    0.851
```

Answer (score 1):

Through split,

```
$ awk '{split($3,a,":");if(a[2]==0){$4=$4-1}}1' file | column -t
1  1:?  1:0  -0.238
2  1:?  2:1  0.754
3  1:?  2:1  0.848
4  1:?  1:0  0
5  1:?  2:1  0.851
```

To print only the 4th column,

```
$ awk '{split($3,a,":");if(a[2]==0){$4=$4-1};print $4}' file
-0.238
0.754
0.848
0
0.851
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it uses only awk:

```
awk '{ if (substr($3,3)==0)
        print ($4-1)
       else print $4
     }' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some other variation:

```
awk '{$0=$4-(substr($3,3)==0?1:0)}1' file
-0.238
0.754
0.848
0
0.851
```

Answer (score 1):

An another answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f


{
    split($3, a, ":");
    if (a[2] == 0) {
        OFS="    ";
        $4 = $4-1;
    }
    print($0);
}
```

And incase if you need a oneliner

```
$ awk '{ split($3, a, ":"); if (a[2] == 0) { OFS="    "; $4 = $4-1; } print($0); }' file.txt
```

Output:

```
1    1:?    1:0    -0.238
2    1:?    2:1    0.754
3    1:?    2:1    0.848
4    1:?    1:0    0
5    1:?    2:1    0.851
```